# How to split a 29 bit value into bytes in C?

Tags: c, gcc

i want to split a 29 bit value into bytes ? how can i accomplish this in C?

```
unsigned long value = 0x18FEF512;
```

I need the output like this val=0x18, val1=FE, val2=F5 , val3=12.

How to do this using bit twidlling?

Comment: Did you look at `>>` operator?

Comment: you need the `&` operator too, me thinks - unless you typecast.

Comment: @isedev not if `val`, `val1`, `val2` `val3` are of the right type.

Comment: How it is a 29 bits number??

Comment: count the significant bits :)

Comment: @isedev Oh! you means 32 - 3 = 29  -- 3 right most zeros..

Comment: do like this `union type {char a, b, c, d, unsigned long value}; type v; v.value = value; then printf("%x, %x, %x, %x", v.a, v.b, v.c, v.b);`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan you have to group `a,b,c,d` together into a `struct` first. considering using gcc and doing bit manipulation, `__u32` could be better.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Thanks Friend :) here is [my code](http://codepad.org/hKcxtXaN) for OP

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Yes your are correct.

Comment: How exactly to do bit manipulation to split that value?

Comment: @ganeshredcobra check this http://codepad.org/AH1e1WOV

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan what about endianness ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
unsigned long value = 0x18FEF512;
unsigned char values[4];
values[0] = value;
values[1] = value >> 8;
values[2] = value >> 16;
values[3] = value >> 24;
printf("%02X %02X %02X %02X\n",values[0],values[1],values[2],values[3]);
```

Comment: What if i want to get FEF5 in one variable then how will i do shifting?

Comment: if you want to get that you should do it this way:
    unsigned short val;
    val = value >> 8;
    printf("%04X",val);

Comment: What's the need of 04X by using %X itself we gets the same value?

Comment: when your short variable is something like 0x00F5, %X will show you "F5" but %04X will show you "00F5"... that is the difference!

Comment: Thank you :) that solves my doubt Bit Twidlling always confuses me. Can you suggest a good tutorial

Comment: You're welcome! I know some books that are good but all of them are just distributed in my country they are not english :( They don't seem to help you much. sorry! Google that there will be a lot of good material.

Comment: ... why do people think this is the answer? It simply isnt : http://codepad.org/acD6p3rr

Comment: Because it matches the question and the OP *said* it solved the problem (both specifically in words, and by accepting this answer). It doesn't get much more clear than that.

Answer (score 2):

Edit per chux comment : this mixes a little C and C++ syntax - see below

The direct way is to put your 29 bit in a `long` or `unsigned long` and do bit shifting :

```
unsigned long value = 0x18FEF512;
unsigned char val0, val1, val2, val3;
val0 = (unsigned char) (value & 0xFF);
value >>= 8;
val1 = (unsigned char) (value & 0xFF);
value >>= 8;
val2 = (unsigned char) (value & 0xFF);
value >>= 8;
val3 = (unsigned char) (value & 0xFF);
```

If you have to do many times, if can be useful to first determine endianness and then directly load bytes. For endianness :

```
int i = 1;
char *ix = (char *) &i;
bool bigendian = (*ix == 0);
```

Then

```
char *bytes = (char *) &value;
if (bigendian) {
    val3 = bytes[0];
    val2 = bytes[1];
    val1 = bytes[2];
    val0 = bytes[3];
}
else {
    val0 = bytes[0];
    val1 = bytes[1];
    val2 = bytes[2];
    val3 = bytes[3];
}
```

Edit

The above mixed C++ syntax by declaring variables all along the code when C wants them at beginning, and using unneeded casts

Here is the same as true C :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned long value = 0x18FEF512;
    unsigned char val0, val1, val2, val3;
    int i = 1;
    char *ix = (char *) &i;
    char bigendian = (*ix == 0);
    char *bytes = (char *) &value;

    val0 = value & 0xFF;
    value >>= 8;
    val1 = value & 0xFF;
    value >>= 8;
    val2 = value & 0xFF;
    value >>= 8;
    val3 = value & 0xFF;
    printf("Bit shifting : %x %x %x %x\n", val0, val1, val2, val3);

    value = 0x18FEF512;

    printf("%System is %s endian", bigendian ? "big" : "little");

    if (bigendian) {
        val3 = bytes[0];
        val2 = bytes[1];
        val1 = bytes[2];
        val0 = bytes[3];
    }
    else {
        val0 = bytes[0];
        val1 = bytes[1];
        val2 = bytes[2];
        val3 = bytes[3];
    }
    printf("Endian aware byte access : %x %x %x %x\n", val0, val1, val2, val3);
}
```

Comment: Why the `(unsigned char)` casts?

Comment: @chux: to avoid warnings for affecting a long to an unsigned char and possibly loosing bits.

Comment: `val0 = (unsigned char) value & 0xFF;` first casts `value` to an `unsigned char`.  Then it is promoted to `int` for the following anding with `0xFF` which is an `int`.  Finally the `int` result is saved as an `unsigned char`.  If anything, thought you would want `val0 = (unsigned char) (value & 0xFF);`.  Isn't the warning you are concerned about a C++ issue and not C?

Comment: Note that `char*` casting is a *rare exception* to the [Strict Aliasing Requirement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).  One should not get in the habit of casting arbitrary pointers from one type to another to peek inside their contents.

Answer (score -5):

What you actually were asking is how to print `string`-segments of a `string`-representation of a `unsigned long` value, this can be achieved in numerous ways.

At first, you will need to get the string-representation of your integral, have a look at [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) and the `%X` format - this will get you an idea of what needs to be done *(tip : there is a similar function to printf which stores the result into your own field instead of printing it to stdout)*

Now you will need to split that resulting string into pieces, [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/?kw=strtok) will do exactly that.
With the resulting tokens you can now fill up a new `char`-array and finally print it.

Good luck with your assignment, you are now equipped with the necessary knowledge.

One more thing : this has nothing to do with "bit twidding" or bit shifting. At all. Maybe there ARE ways to calculate the integral segments which are equal to the string-segments but i highly doubt anyone would willingly do the math behind it - that'd basically be "re-inventing the wheel" which doesnt even serve educational purposes ...

Comment: But you are not splitting into bytes as asked by OP ... and do you know that bit shifting are among the simplest operation for the processor, even simpler than an addition because you have no carry propagation and all can be done in the same internal processor cycle ?

Comment: Where did you get this idea? I don't see any evidence for it. Quotes please.

Comment: I don't see how `strtok` could be used here. What delimiters do you propose? Besides, converting to string and then back to bytes is needlessly overcomplicating things. Simply perform bit shifting followed by masking and be done with it.